# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, while using Java 8 streams to iterate a list

Tags: java-8

I have a List of Objects  called md. Each of this objects has an activityName, a startTime and an endTime(for the activity).
I want to iterate over this list and for each activity, get the startTime and endTime.

```
Map<String,Long> m1 = new HashMap<String,Long>();
        m1 = md
                .stream()
                .map(s->s.activityName)
                .collect(HashMap<String,Long>::new,
                    (map,string)->{
                        String d1 = md.get(md.indexOf(string)).startTime;
                        String d2 = md.get(md.indexOf(string)).endTime;
                           .
                           .
                           .
                 },HashMap<String,Long>::putAll);
```

It gives me  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 when I try to get the index of string   `String d1 = md.get(md.indexOf(string)).startTime;`

Is there any other way to simplify the code using Lambda expressions?

What if I have two activities with the same name (Drinking for ex).Will it only return the index of the first Drinking activity it finds?

Comment: It's unclear what the result should be. But since your list is a List<SomeObject>, calling indexOf(activityName) on in will always return -1. The String activityName is not equal to any of the SomeObject instances stored in the list. Your strategy s also extremely inefficient, since it needs to find the object in the list at each iteration, although the stream precisely iterates on these objects.

Comment: it is interesting, but if I want to print the activityName of the string , it displays it right.        System.out.println(string), displays " Sleeping" , but still, it says that it`s index is -1.

Comment: of course it does. after the `map` operation your Stream is `Stream<String>`  and you are printing this string...

Comment: I got it. But how can I fix my problem? What`s the right way to iterrate the List?

Comment: its not clear what you actually what to achieve - a more clear example would help. btw you can tag people in your comments via `@`, like `@Eugene`.

Comment: Be precise on what the type of your objects is, and on what you want to achieve. You said "for each activity , get the startTime and endTime", but the result is a Map<String,Long>. I don't see how you could store a start time and an end time in a Long. Even if you could, there is no guarantee that two objects don't have the same activity name. You should also be precise on that point.

Comment: well, I want to get every activity with its startTime and endTime ,from the list. and for each activity , calculate the time it takes (endTime-startTime).I want to put each activity and its duration in the m1 map

Comment: I have to use Streams, this is the requirement @JBNizet

Comment: @JBNizet There have been similar questions with this requirement for about a week. This seems to be an assignment. They have a list of `MonitoredData` or similar object, which has an activity name, a start time and an end time. They need to find out the total duration for each activity, and yes, there can be more than one `MonitoredData` instance with the same activity. I've even seen a second part of the assignment in which they need to order the map by duration in descendant order and keep only the top 10 activities. I think all the related questions are duplicates of the original one...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are missing that fact that once you do:

```
md.stream().map(s -> s.activityName)
```

your Stream has become `Stream<String>`; while your md is still `List<YourObject>`

And in the map operation you are trying to find a `String` inside `md`, this obviously does not exist, thus a `-1`.

So you need a `Map<String, Long>` that is `activitaName -> duration it takes(could be Date/Long)`

```
 md.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.activityName, x -> {
       Date start = // parse s.startTime
       Date end = // parse s.endTime
       return end.minus(start);
    }));
```

Now the parsing depends on the dates you use.

Comment: Eugene, please see my comment in the question, you still need to manage collisions, because there can be more than one object in the list with the same activity name.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner thx... let's close this question then.